# Using Zephyr Rest API to get all test cases

Tags: jira-rest-api

I have a requirement to pull all test cases from Zephyr scale using the rest api. I am using below endpoint to fetch it, but the problem is that all the test cases are residing under test tab which are not pulled from the above endpoint.

https:///rest/api/2/search?jql=project=Prj